# How to create this kind of UI

Tags: android, user-interface

May i know how can i create this kind of UI, please see the pic posted below.

[image]

Is it simple linear layout having some different sized buttons, or different image controls or what exactly is this?. How can i create UI of this sort.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Note that this is a copy paste from my own code and there are certain attributes which are posted below this code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/nav_bar"
    style="@style/TitleBar" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"    >
        <ImageButton 
            style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnStatusUpdate"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tab_compose_selected" >
        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView style="@style/TitleBarSeparator" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbarTitle"
        android:text="ACTIVITY"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center_horizontal|center"
        android:padding="5dp"   >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView style="@style/TitleBarSeparator" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"    >
        <ImageButton 
            style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnStatusUpdate"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tab_compose_selected" >
        </ImageButton>
     </LinearLayout>
     <ImageView style="@style/TitleBarSeparator" />
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"    >
            <ImageButton
                style="@style/TitleBarAction"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnUploadPhoto"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_tab_camera_selected"  >
        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Style elements for the code above. This goes in your `styles.xml`:

```
    <style name="TitleBar">
        <item name="android:id">@id/title_container</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">45dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBarSeparator">
        <item name="android:layout_width">1px</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:background">USE A COLOR OF YOUR CHOICE HERE</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, my requirement was to make 3 tabs and one search button at the corner, i can achieve the same by modifying the layout which you have provided right..

Comment: Yes you can. Think of this as a kind of a template. Just add your element instead of the ImageButtons in the code.

Comment: we can use image button itself to act as tabs right.. based on the width and in the corner, we can place a small search image.. i hope my idea make sense right.. as i m new i am asking your advice

Comment: That is correct. The screenshot you have as an example is not really a Tab implementation. This is an Action Bar. In short, replace one of the Imagebuttons in my example with your image and set the code to that image which applies your search function.

Comment: Yes, siddarth, u r right.. one more thing last one,i'm sorry if i m disturbing u more.. when i tap on search icon, as search bar should move from right to left.. can we provide effect of that sort?, and we can just gray the color of tabs and provide focus for search window right?

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's not disturbing at all. But I am not sure I follow your question. You want to hide the other elements when the Search button is pressed?

Comment: Yes, please... actually in my implementation search is required.. if i place search below the tab, it simply eat space. instead my plan is to  show search window when the search icon is pressed, that too over tabs.. i want to give some kinda moment effect as if search window is dropping from top or moving from left.

Comment: Well, in all honesty, I have never needed a search function in any of my apps so far. So never played around with any such implementations. However, I guess you could play around with the add an EditText, set it's attribute 'android:visibility="gone"' to start with and then make it visible with animations when the button is pressed. And also, set the visibility of the TextView and any other elements you do not wish to be displayed to 'Gone' from the Java code when the button is pressed. Again, I think this is how I would do it. Atleast to begin with.

Comment: Ok, siddharth, ill try and post code, if i face some difficulty... thanks for your response.. thanks lot

Comment: No problem fella. Glad to have been of some help. ;-)

Comment: Siddharth, as i digged more into the action bar, i found customizing them is little tedious, i found actionbarsherlock is the best way to implement actionbars, so do you have any idea about how to use it?

Comment: @LLL: Sorry for the late reply. Was caught up with some work. I am trying out ABS. But I am not quite up to the mark. Perhaps, you could start playing around with it a bit. I have also been trying GreenDroid and experimenting with it.

Comment: i mean, i should upgrade my SDK version to 4.0 and then use ABS or is it fine to use with V2.2.. this s what my question is

Comment: Apparently, it works. I haven't tested it so far. And you target the SDK 15 (or honeycomb. I am not sure) and set the min SDK version as 8. That has worked for me so far.

Comment: For doing this, i should install Latest Android SDK i.e ICS or Honeycomb correct?

Comment: Correct. You will need them installed.

Comment: Ok, fine as per your suggestion i will install ICS and try today.. Thanks for your help... ill ask you if i req any help

Answer (score 1):

It's action bar. You can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or
Google [ActionBarCompat - Action Bar Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) example to achieve this look and feel

Comment: as i digged more into the action bar, i found customizing them is little tedious, i found actionbarsherlock is the best way to implement actionbars, so do you have any idea about how to use it?

Comment: I think you should start with Demos Sample project from [github page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples/demos) or you can find them in samples derictory of actionbarsherlock zip

Comment: Actually i'm using Android V2.2 Emulator, i'm unable to import the library... what could be the problem. i should upgrade the latest SDK

Comment: May be 1) Upgrate ADT 2)target you app to ICS, and minSdk to Froyo 3) try to add v4 support library first. I use it in may projects, and it work properly, no problems with importing. Take a look at [usage](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) page

Comment: Style, you mean, i should upgrade my SDK to V 4.0 and then play with Actionsherlock you are talking?.. what is that v4 support lib? i m new to it

Comment: set your android:targetSdkVersion to 15, and minSdkVersion to 8 in manifest. Then add to workspace existing project of library folder in actionbarsherlock source, in properties of you project link it as library. Then add to you project support lib. Follow [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#SettingUp) to setup it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11568/discussion-between-style-and-lll)

Comment: i followed your procedure, some new problems have arsed..i installed ICS V4.0 android SDK, when i create a project using Actionbarsherlock its giving me manifest.xml is missing error... any idea?

Comment: try to import project, not to create from existing source

Comment: glad it got worked.. now i am able to build sample examples given in ABS SDK.. thanks for your support.. But one more thing i would like to know few more things.. i.e can we add our own custom listview developed in Android 2.2 SDK to ABS.. i.e when i switch tabs, the list should display items with small image... i have got adapter class and all, can we bind it to ABS tabview, these kind of support is allowed right?..

Comment: yes, it's possible to do anything you want with UI, because tabs in ABS are just part of action bar. In you layout you can use ListView and set custom adapter to it

Comment: thanks lot.. i will try to play with them & ask u in case if i find any trouble..please respond and stay in touch with me.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ... >
    <ImageView ... android:layout_weight="0.1" .../>
    <TextView ... android:layout_weight="0.7" .../>
    <ImageView ... android:layout_weight="0.1" .../>
    <ImageView ... android:layout_weight="0.1" .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u give me a sample example link, if u have?

Comment: I've edited my answer so you'll have the basic layout set and you can play with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create it. Just change background color and set images on image button. Change text and its style and I think it will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" android:background="#0000ff">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:background="#0000ff"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="xxx"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:background="#0000ff"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:background="#0000ff"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```